# Creating a userlogin with token and tokensecret

Tags: dropnet

I'm using Dropnet library to communicate with Dropbox.

After I accept the first time that my account allows my APP I save the token and secret forn next time I can process whatever I want without asking the user again.

But after I do this code:

```
Try
   client.UserLogin = New UserLogin()
   client.UserLogin.Token = dropboxAtoken
   client.UserLogin.Secret = dropboxAsecret

   Dim accountInfo As AccountInfo = client.AccountInfo()
      ' More of my code
Catch ex As DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException
   messagebox.show(ex.Message.ToString)
End Try
```

I receive this error:

{"error": "Parameter not found: oauth_token"}

Can anyone help please.

Comment: Just found in code that the lines: client.UserLogin.Token = dropboxAtoken and client.UserLogin.Secret = dropboxAsecret does not put transfer their values to the private properties in OAuthAuthenticator.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the overload on the DropNetClient constructor that takes both API keys and User tokens that way it will get correctly wired up.

Or create the instance of the UserLogin first then set it on the client.
See the code for the setter of that parameter wires it up when setting it:
https://github.com/DropNet/DropNet/blob/master/DropNet/Client/Client.cs#L32